# How can I record a website demo as an animated SVG like this?

Tags: svg, browser, demo

I have never seen this before and am excited to learn how this was accomplished.

How can I record a website demo as an animated SVG like [this](https://stytch.com/images/pages/home/hero-gif.svg)?

[image: from https://stytch.com/]

I found https://github.com/marionebl/svg-term-cli, but that seems to be limited to terminal sessions rather than browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a month looking for the answer.

Finally I decided I should just ask them.

They answered right away.

> Our team designed and laid out the frames in that SVG in Figma, and then animated them using https://www.svgator.com/.
> I hope that's helpful – best of luck!
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Stytch Support

So, it sounds like there isn't an automated way. Just hard work.